# The file <filename> cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents.In some cases

Tags: office-addins

I am copying any document to my office-addin 2010. It gives error for only in some unpredictable cases, when copy the contents of word document and open office-addin - 
The file  cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents.  Details: Microsoft Office can't open this file because some parts are missing or invalid.  Location: Part: /word/document.xml, line: 1, column: 0
It ask Do you want to recover the contents of the document?
Then open it in another document.

Answer (score 0):

1) make a backup copy..

2) you can try "OPEN and REPAIR" from "FILE" menu ...

3) if not, you can open file with **LIBRE-OFFICE** or similar software...  you may loose formatting ,but you will get contents at least..

4) if not, try - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918429

5) if not, try google "Word repair software" (like [yodot solution](http://www.yodot.com/doc-repair/after-error-opening-docx-file.html), [staroffice](http://www.staroffice.com/get.php) or etc..)